# ¿Cómo evitar valores duplicados en la misma fila al momento de insertar o actualizar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy creando una aplicación tipo red social, donde sigues personas (Twitter, Instagram, etc..) y me he encontrado con que quiero relacionar dos campos hacia la misma tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
Tabla Perfiles:
+----+-----------+------+-----+
| ID | IDUsuario | Nick | ... |
+----+-----------+------+-----+

Tabla Relaciones (Follows)
+----+------------+-----------+-----+
| ID | IDSeguidor | IDSeguido | ... |
+----+------------+-----------+-----+
```

Donde "Seguidor" y "Seguido" hacen referencia al campo ID de la tabla 'Perfiles'

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el IDSeguidor sea diferente de IDSeguido, es decir, para evitar que el usuario se 'siga' a si mismo (Desde el lado de SQL)?

Comment: Crear un "BEFORE" Trigger, donde inspeccionar si de dos son semejante.

Comment: Si es para SQL Server, veo que debes hacer un trigger `AFTER INSERT` y una operación de `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más fácil un [CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx)

> Es un constraint que obliga a integridad limitando los posibles valores que pueden ser introducido en una columna o columnas.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Relaciones]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Relaciones] CHECK  (([IDSeguidor]<>[IDSeguido]))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Relaciones] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Relaciones]
GO
```

También puedes quitar el campo ID de tu tabla relaciones y usar una llave compuesta con IDSeguidor e IDSeguido, como las llaves deben ser únicas se obliga a que la combinación de ambos valores sea único también.

Comment: ¿Esto básicamente verifica si el usuario intenta seguirse a si mismo? 
Por lo que puedo leer, el operador '<>' significa "es diferente de", lo que quiere decir que si ambas llaves son iguales, me arrojará algún tipo de error, ¿No?

Comment: Si ambas llaves son iguales no te permitirá insertar la fila o modificar una existente y lanzará un error

Comment: Si, acabo de probarlo y es justamente lo que necesito, gracias!

Comment: @DatchM Puedes usar un [TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189799%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) también pero en realidad es mucho código boilerplate para algo que puede lograrse con unas pocas líneas de código como puedes apreciar.